# is Destructor really destroy memory or just runs before the lifetime of object is going to end?

Tags: c++, static, local, destructor, new-operator

> there are few question like this but not exactly same so please care
> to read whole question before cast it as duplicate one

#### 1. objects created using `new` keyword (dynamic objects).

we explicitly use `delete` keyword to de-allocate there memory. so when program encounter delete keyword it get sense that object is going to end so it runs there destructor. is destructor de-allocate there memory ? I don't think so, as if we created destructor manually and do not code anything, just empty destructor still de-allocation is happen. means I feel destructor runs and then control get back to `delete` keyword and then memory de-allocation done.

**if I am wrong** please correct me.

**if I am right** then what's about if I call destructor manually for these dynamic objects with help of pointer `p->~destructor()`(where p is ptr pointing to these dynamic memory) it will de-allocate memory or not ?
**if not** then while `delete` command it not goes into `undefined behavior` `UB` right ? **if yes** but how is going to de-allocate memory as destructor do not de-allocate memory and it has not `delete` command also. (I know when it reach `delete` it goes into `UB`)

#### 2. Local objects

when there scope is going to end there memory destroyed. so when program encounter end of scope it get sense that particular object is going to end so it runs it's destructor and after that control back to called place(just before ending of scope) and then variable get out of scope and memory destroyed.

**if I am wrong** please correct me.

**if I am right** then what's about if I call destructor manually for this local object `a. ~destructor` (where a is local object) it will destroy memory or not ? **if not**  while scope is going to end destructor invokes, then it not goes into `UB` right. **if yes** then how it is going to destroyed memory. as destructor do not de-allocate memory and it did not reach the end of scope also.

#### 3. static objects

I think only difference between `static` and `local` objects is `static` destroyed while program is going to end and `local` destroyed when scope is going to end, so what is applicable for `local objects` regarding destructor, destruction of object is also applicable to `static objects`

#### 4. if destructor do not de-allocate memory then what actually it does ?

my teacher says that destructor just give a moment to tell that these objects are going to destroyed so we can finish some stuff regarding these objects, **is he right ?** Also please tell extra points what destructor does.

Comment: What is your definition of "destroying memory"? You may edit the question.

Comment: `if not then while delete command it not goes into undefined behavior UB right ?` What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or just runs before the lifetime of object is going to end?

To be clear: The lifetime of the object ending and the calling of the destructor happen in the same point in time, not one after the other.

> is destructor de-allocate there memory ?

Not necessarily. See following example for details.

> 4. if destructor do not de-allocate memory then what actually it does ?

Let's consider following class:

```
struct example : base {
    another_class member;
    ~example() {
        // destructor body
    }
};
```

The destructor of `example` first executes the "destructor body", then it executes the destructors of all sub objects (which consists of `member` and `base` in this example). If the body, or the destructor of any sub object deallocates some memory, then that's what the destructor does. But the memory of the object being destroyed is generally not deallocated by the destructor.

Indeed, `delete` does two things: Call the destructor, and dealloate the storage.

> what's about if I call destructor manually for these dynamic objects with help of pointer p->~destructor()(where p is ptr pointing to these dynamic memory)

That destroys the object.

> it will destroy memory or not ?

The storage is not deallocated by an explicit call to a destructor.

> then what's about if I call destructor manually for this local object a. ~destructor (where a is local object) it will destroy memory or not ?

The storage is not deallocated by an explicit call to a destructor regardless of where the object is stored.

> if not while scope is going to end destructor invokes, then it not goes into UB right.

If a destroyed object in automatic storage goes out of scope, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: @eeroika l would like to upvote you but my reputation is not enough. Let it be. Thanks, I get clear in difference between destruction of object and destruction of memory.

Comment: @Tylerdurden You should be able to accept an answer regardless of reputation. You can vote later when you have reputation.

Comment: `To be clear: The lifetime of the object ending and the calling of the destructor happen in the same point in time, not one after the other.`  can I access member variables of object in it's destructor or it is going to `undefined behavior` ?

Comment: @Tylerdurden You can. The sub objects' lifetimes end after the destructor body returns.

Comment: sub objects means member variables of objects right  ? and what's about object lifetime it also end after the destructor body returns  or what ?

Comment: @Tylerdurden Member objects and base sub objects. The object lifetime ends at the same point when the destructor is called.

Comment: `Member objects and base sub objects` I don't get it what are you trying to say. __struct complex { private: `int a, b`;  `day d` ; public:__  // some functions __};__ here `d` is object of struct type day. `complex c1` ;  when destructor for `c1` gets called __1.__ is object `c1` is destroyed ? __2.__ is int type variables `a,b` get destroyed __3__ is object of day type `d` get destroyed all these thing destroyed beginning of destuctor of `c1` or at the end of destructor.

Comment: and what are the sub objects in above structure.

Comment: @Tylerdurden 1. yes. 2. yes 3. yes. after the destructor body. The subobjects are a, b and d.

Comment: okay but in your 2nd last comment you said `The object lifetime ends at the same point when the destructor is called.` this is contrary to what you said in your last comment , isn't it ?

Comment: @Tylerdurden How so? As I said, the object is destroyed when the destructor is called. Similarly, the destructor is called when the object is destroyed. They both happen simultaneously. I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: `after the destructor body.`

Comment: @Tylerdurden That's when the subobjects are destroyed and their destructors called by the super object destructor. Not at the beginning, like you suggested in the  comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67530327/is-destructor-really-destroy-memory-or-just-runs-before-the-lifetime-of-object-i/67530411?noredirect=1#comment119385906_67530411

Comment: I almost get clear just want to confirm I asked you by numbering __1__ object `c1`  __2__ ---  __3__ --- are all these things are destroyed beginning of destructor of c1 or at the end of destructor.  you said `after the destructor of body` means object 'c1` destroyed after the destructor of body. That's what I am trying to say that it is contrary what you said because you said this statement for all 3 cases not just for 2nd or 3rd case.

Comment: @Tylerdurden Oh yeah, I forgot that c1 was included in all, so my reply was misleading. The lifetim of c1 has already ended when the execution of destructor body begins (because the call and the end of lifetime happend simultaneously), and the lifetime of the sub objects end after the destructor body.

Comment: so if I try to access object in destructor with the help of `this` pointer it will be case of `undefined behavior`  as object is already destroyed right   ?

Comment: __2__ is there are compiler defined implicit constructors  and destructors are present for primitive data type variables like `int a` or it is concept only for object and class ?

Comment: please answer these two questions. I will not bother you again., these last two only. please.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at C. It hasn't `new` and `delete` keywords. It has `malloc` and `free`. `malloc` just allocates memory without initializing, `free` just deallocates.
C++ has `new` and `delete`. `new` allocates memory and calls constructor, `delete` calls destructor and deallocates object.

When you call ~destructor() you just clean object data but it still exists in memory.

Variable allocated with `new` stores on the heap. Local valiables stored on stack, static stored in data segment.